# How to hide TabBar in RootView ChildViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am troubling in hide `UITabBarController` inside the *TabBar* item `ChildViewControllers`

**For Ex.** Suppose We have two tab bar item in my home screen and first tab bar item is selected and i want to go with navigate first tab bar then i want to hide *TabBar* in first *TabBar* item `childViewControllers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this

```
 [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

use hide Tab bar item in viewDidLoad using hidden property.
And Select Under Opaque Bars option in storyBoard ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

before view is pushed or showed. hidesBottomBarWhenPushed variable on viewcontroll will be checked and automaticlly hides bottom bar. you can use it in two ways:

1- override it in child controllers:

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    return true
}
```

2- you can set it before performing segue in prepare for segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        segue.destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    }
}
```